# ASP.NET AJAX UpdatePanel scrolling problem

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanel, focus, vertical-scrolling

I'll try and be concise:

1. I have a dropdownlist with `Autopostback` set to `true`
2. I have an UpdatePanel that contains a `Label`.
3. When the downdownlist selection is changed, I want to update the label.

Problem: Focus is lost on the dropdownlist, forcing the user to click on the dropdownlist to reset focus back to the control.

My "solution": In the `DropDownList_SelectionChanged` event, set focus back to the drop down list:

```
dropdownlist1.focus()
```

While this works great in IE, Firefox and Chrome change the scroll position such that the control which was assigned focus is positioned at the bottom on the visible portion of the browser window. This is often a very disorientating side effect.

How can this be avoided so it works in FF as it does in IE?

Comment: I will I could offer a bounty right off the bat on this one. I need an answer. I'm looking for a solution that does not involve abandoning teh UpdatePanel control.

Answer (score 3):

Try **MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback** in one of these 3 ways

- Programmatically - Page.MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack = true;
- Page declaration - <%@ Page MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" %>
- In the web.config - <pages maintainScrollPositionOnPostBack="true" />

You may also need to add this javascript after the scriptmanager declaration:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

prm.add_beginRequest(beginRequest);

function beginRequest()
{
    prm._scrollPosition = null;
}

</script>
```

Comment: Boy, I got excited-until I tried it and it didn't work. I added it to the project root web.config. I'm using VS2010 RC

Comment: Lets try putting in the page declaration and adding some script after the script manager (I had this problem, it sucked, I eventually got it to work)

Comment: Nope, that didn't seem to help.

Comment: Remove the focus code from the server code.
use setTimer in script about 100ms after page is loaded to reset focus. (jquery will help here)

Answer (score 1):

Velika - Sorry for the delay.
If you are using a master page add :

```
<asp:ScriptManagerProxy runat="server" ID="smp"></asp:ScriptManagerProxy>
```

Otherwise just add

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" id="sm" />
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    prm.add_beginRequest(beginRequest);

    function beginRequest() {
        prm._scrollPosition = window.top;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the exact same issue and got the answer. Hope this helps :
http://forums.asp.net/p/1622050/4164858.aspx#4164858

```
 <script type="text/javascript">  
 var xPos, yPos;  
 var postBackElement;  

 var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();  
 prm.add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);  
 prm.add_initializeRequest(InitializeRequest);  

 function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {  
     if (postBackElement != null) {  
         document.getElementById(postBackElement.id).focus();  
     }  
 }  
 function InitializeRequest(sender, args) {    
      postBackElement = args.get_postBackElement();    
  }
```

Comment: Javascript and I don't know what the PageRequestManager object is: http://screencast.com/t/T8pSyZW1vw
Plz help.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void SetFocusByJavaScript(Page page, string clientID)
        {
            string uniqueScriptId = String.Concat("focusScript", clientID);
            string scriptBody = String.Format("setTimeout(\"$get('{0}').focus();\", 100);", clientID);
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(page, page.GetType(), uniqueScriptId, scriptBody, true);
        }
```

This is how I have been getting around this issue.  The example requires jquery, but you could rewrite if needed.  Basically just delays the focus script.