# How would I nest a unique UpdatePanel within a DataList at the ItemTemplate Level?

Tags: .net, dynamic, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I've successfully nested the DataList in a single UpdatePanel.  However, the performance is less than desirable (2 - 8 second refreshes, I need 1 second).  It also presents a usability problem as the UpdatePanel updates, the browser snaps to wherever the user was at the point of page refresh (in FireFox).

In hopes of increasing individual item refreshes, I wanted to implement unique updatepanels within each itemtemplate of the datalist.  However, the application will not build, as UpdatePanel1 errors out as not existing in current context.

Suggestions?  Work arounds? Alternative approaches?  All are welcome.

Respectfully,

Ray K. Ragan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to work around the problem; here's my solution:

1. I rewrote the SQL to make the query time much snappier, which was where the bulk of my latency was coming from.  The updates routinely happen at 1 second now.
2. The scrollbar solution was posted previously, here's the code you need in your .aspx page:

[James Westgate's Solution on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547763/asp-net-ajax-updatepanel-problem)