# maintainScrollPositionOnPostBack doesn't work when i use updatePanel

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, maintainscrollpositionon

I take advantage of an update panel and would like to use the `ScrollPositioning` but it doesn't work.

I use  `maintainScrollPositionOnPostBack="true"` in .aspx pages.

What can I do so that it works?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET AJAX UpdatePanel problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547763/asp-net-ajax-updatepanel-problem)

Comment: sorry but it doesn't solved my problem. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the possible sollutions taken from Personal Blog of Mustafa Başgün
[image]
https://basgun.wordpress.com/2008/06/09/maintain-scroll-position-updatepanel-postback/

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this solution (require jQuery):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var docScrollTop;
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

    function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {
        docScrollTop= $(document).scrollTop();
    }

    function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
        $(document).scrollTop(docScrollTop);
    }

    prm.add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
    prm.add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);

</script>
```